# How long it would take for a USPTO application to get republished?

Tags: uspto, claim-amendment

If I amend my claims after normal publication (18 months), I believe my application will get republished again with amended claims.

How long that process would take?

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: @EricShain If 35 U.S.C. 154(d) says `as claimed in the published patent application`. I'm not sure whether my amended claims need to be republished again to claim royalty. That's why I asked this question. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application will NOT be republished. The amended claims will be added to the applications file history (called the 'Image File Wrapper' in both Public PAIR and Private PAIR), almost always the same day as they are received. The amended claims are view-able as submitted, and are not incorporated into the body of the application in any way.

The Patent Office will also publish the application with all of the amendments in its final form once the application issues into a Granted Patent.

However, if you would really like to republish an application before Issuance, according to [MPEP 1130(I)](https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/pac/mpep/s1130.html) the Patent Office will republish amended applications if you request it along with:

1. The amended application
2. A publication fee of $300
3. A processing fee (between $70 and $140)

Comment: Thanks Gabriel. Will I get provisional protection, if my amended claims don't get published? I mean it's added to the 'Image File Wrapper' in both Public PAIR and Private PAIR. But not get published. Or provisional protection applicable only to published claims?

Comment: @Giri There really isn't any "provisional protection". If your patent eventually is granted, then you have protection for the granted claims dating back to the provisional filing date. Only the granted claims matter. Published but un-granted claims in applications don't matter in the least.

Comment: @EricShain Hi Eric, I think I worded my question poorly. I'm talking about "provisional rights". 35 U.S.C. 154(d) to be precise. It says something like this. `if the invention as claimed in the published patent application is a process, uses, offers for sale, or sells in the United States or imports into the United States products made by that process as claimed in the published patent application`. So let me rephrase that question. To claim royalty from the claim published date, do I have to republish it again or sending a notice to the person who copied my work would suffice?

Comment: @Giri I'm not a lawyer, but if the amended claims become part of the file wrapper and thus publicly available isn't that good enough?

Comment: @EricShain It's definitely good enough if the court ok with that :-) In most cases, these infringers try to find loopholes. I have just read the adobe vs rosebud case. Where adobe escaped because they didn't have the actual notice even though they have the full knowledge. https://www.theiplawblog.com/2016/03/articles/patent-law/pre-issuance-damages-for-patent-infringement-a-very-rare-remedy/

Comment: @Giri Are you expecting your claims won’t be amended during prosecution?

Comment: @EricShain Yes, I'm narrowing my claims to make sure I don't have to amend it during prosecution. See this page. https://www.obrienpatents.com/patent-application-provisional-rights-stop-infringers/ `.
In order to obtain provisional rights, the invention claimed in the published application needs to be “substantially identical” to the invention claimed in the issued patent.  This means that you cannot have any narrowing amendments.  Only 15% of applications issue without narrowing amendments, so the number of patent applications eligible for provisional rights is small.`

Comment: @Giri The problem with narrowing your claims is that you still probably won't get them granted without changes and you give up the potential for a broader claim that might issue. I've got 88 patents and I wouldn't dream of trying to write and prosecute my own claims. There is simply too much legal knowledge needed. If you write your claims narrowly you might get a few of them granted, but then leave it too easy to circumvent them. All for the slight likelihood of some limited royalties for the time pre-grant. Seems like a bad idea to me

Comment: @Giri I'm not a lawyer (just an agent) and have no exp with such matters. But if you believe there is a potential infringement, the application must be published and the infringer must be notified. Penalties would be paid from the date of notice (once you win in court). Obviously your invention date must be from before the infringer's public release of their product. As to the breadth of the claims, you should use dependent claims that more narrowly define your product as is. Your independent claims should claim all the inventive subject matter allowable to you, as you understand it

Comment: @GabrielHendricks Thanks for the info. I have one more question. Is sending an email considered as notice or it has to be a physical mail?

Comment: @Giri  Good luck to you.

Comment: @EricShain Thanks :-)

Comment: @Giri Just so you know, designing around existing IP is a completely legit practice. Its why getting sufficiently broad claims are important.

Comment: @EricShain Completely agree. Thanks.

Comment: @Giri I don't know, I doubt that an un-certified email would count. But I do know that there are many legal issues when it comes to notices. You should consult patent attorney on the how and the specific wording of any communications to the potential infringer.

Comment: @GabrielHendricks Noted with Thanks

Comment: @EricShain For information, Amended claims cannot claim provisional rights unless they get republished. https://www.uspto.gov/web/offices/com/sol/og/2016/week52/TOCCN/item-385.htm Also some USPTO republication requests mentions "provisional rights". e.g. App No. 11/575,532 => "Request/Corrected Patent Application Publications" contains text like this. `the provisional rights applicant seek to enforce upon issuance of a patent`

Answer (score -1):

Non provisional patent applications are published 18 months from the effective filing date - You may request to publish earlier than that.

Comment: Hi, this question's context is RE-publication. Thanks